# Is it possible make hot swap on weblogic 12?

Tags: javascript, weblogic, swap, hotswap

Front End: AngularJS

Back End: Java

Our employer decided to use Weblogic 12 to deploy the project. So our problem is:

**Is there is any way to modify a javascript file and see the change immediately?** (e.g. a host swap in weblogic)

Note: We don't use Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying an ear/war file, you can hot swap a new version in via the following methods:

This is how you would do it in a production environment with the admin console:

- From the Weblogic admin console, click Deployments, click the checkbox next to your ear/war
- Click Update
- The next screen will ask you for the source path - choose your new file here. You can also change the deployment plan path if you use one

You can also call `java weblogic.Deployer` with the update option if you want to do it from the [command line](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/wldeployer.html#1008424).

It is also possible to do the same via WLST scripting - see these [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/updateplan.htm)

If you're interested in hot swapping JSP pages without a recompile - see the use of `nostage` for your [deployments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/deploy.html#wp1024366)

Comment: Surely this isn't hotswapping at all... this is doing a full deployment.

Comment: An "Update" in weblogic is very similar to a hot swap because it requires no down time (which is what I assume most people are looking for).